# Spring Boot fails to start using Atomikos and JMS MQ connections fails

Tags: spring-boot, jms, atomikos

I have a Spring Boot app using IBM MQ and MySQL DB.

I recently added Atomikos to leverage XA support and all works as expected.  I have a requirement to be able to start the service even if the JMS connection fails. This worked before I introduced Atomikos but it appears that Atomikos has a hard dependency for all data sources to be active.

Is there a way around this so that the Spring Boot app will continue to start even though the JMS connection isn't good?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userTransactionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/transaction/jta/AtomikosJtaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.atomikos.datasource.ResourceException: Error in getting XA resource
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1771) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1271) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1191) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1159) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1271) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1191) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1159) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1271) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.getIfAvailable(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1903) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.<init>(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:94) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.15.RELEASE.jar:2.1.15.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.<init>(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:98) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.15.RELEASE.jar:2.1.15.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4fd877d1.<init>(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.15.RELEASE.jar:2.1.15.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_92]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:300) ~[spring-beans-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        ... 28 more
    Caused by: com.atomikos.datasource.ResourceException: Error in getting XA resource
        at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.jms.JmsTransactionalResource.refreshXAConnection(JmsTransactionalResource.java:80) ~[transactions-jta-4.0.6.jar:?]
        at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XATransactionalResource.refreshXAResource(XATransactionalResource.java:459) ~[transactions-jta-4.0.6.jar:?]
        at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XATransactionalResource.recover(XATransactionalResource.java:451) ~[transactions-jta-4.0.6.jar:?]
        at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XATransactionalResource.setRecoveryService(XATransactionalResource.java:416) ~[transactions-jta-4.0.6.jar:?]
        at com.atomikos.icatch.config.Configuration.notifyAfterInit(Configuration.java:466) ~[transactions-api-4.0.6.jar:?]
        at com.atomikos.icatch.config.Configuration.init(Configuration.java:450) ~[transactions-api-4.0.6.jar:?]
        at com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp.initialize(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:105) ~[transactions-api-4.0.6.jar:?]
        at com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:219) ~[transactions-api-4.0.6.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stack-trace the error is happening specifically during "recovery" initialization. Recovery is a key part of XA transaction management as it allows the manager to deal with "in-doubt" transactions (i.e. transactions that have been prepared but not committed).

According to [this post from the Atomikos website](https://www.atomikos.com/Blog/ExtremeTransactions4dot0dot40) you can disable recovery using these settings:

```
com.atomikos.icatch.enable_logging=none
com.atomikos.icatch.oltp_max_retries=0
```

In my opinion this is not optimal and borderline dangerous as you could get inconsistent data without proper recovery, and the whole point of using XA transactions in the first place is to ensure data consistency.

Comment: Tried those properties but service still failed to start.  What are your thoughts on trapping the exception via some spring boot startup event? (i.e. prevent the exception from bubbling up)

Comment: I rarely use Spring so I can't comment on the viability of that approach.

Comment: No problem.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score -1):

Disabling recovery is not the best way to go.

Maybe check the privileges of the JMS account you are using?

If that does not work, consider getting a free trial of Atomikos:

https://www.atomikos.com/Main/ExtremeTransactionsFreeTrial

It includes free support during the trial, and could help you get this setup. It does require a budget for upgrading to the commercial edition though.